# What's the difference between an iterable and a list in python 3?

Tags: python, list, iterable

Under the hood, aren't iterables just lists? What's the use of having wrappers like `map` `filter` `list` and others like them? What does something being a `filter` actually tell you, except for it's origin? When would (except for being shorter in for example list comprehensions) `x` be better than `list(x)` where `x` is an iterable?

One thing I've heard is that keeping `map` and `filter` as iterables is faster than using them as lists. Why is this? What difference is there under the hood that makes iterables faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between iterable and list is like the difference between a flower and a rose.

All roses are flower, but not all flowers are rose.

All lists are iterable, but not all iterables are lists.

> iterable
>
> An object capable of returning its members one at a time. Iterables include all sequences type (like list, str, and tuples).

List is an iterable, and is having some other more specifics characteristics to list.

Check this out: https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html especially on iterable part.

Comment: so poetic -----